# Wildfly as an automatic service windows

Tags: windows-services, wildfly, wildfly-9

I found the possibility to create a windows service with a Wildfly 9.0.1 Final. But my question is more how can I create an automatic service out of this?

I like to have this on installation time, instead of doing this manually. My expertise on this is not that good, and don't find anything on my search results.

Kr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there I fix my problem of 2 days figuring out how it works.
By bad for all the persons looking for the same answer.

JBoss Wildfly the [procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) from Apache.
So in the script of Wildfly I added the --Startup=auto and then the service was installed as an automatic service